# Eclipse CDT pkg-config addon not detecting gtk3 on fedora

Tags: c, eclipse, fedora, pkg-config

I searched a lot, and I cant find anyone on the internet with the problem I have. 
I always used Eclipse with pkg-config addon installed. On Ubuntu based distributions, like Xubuntu, Mint, Voyager. Always the thing to do was download Eclipse from www.eclipse.org, install gtk+3.0-dev, then in eclipse download the pkg-config plugin, and everything worked perfect.
Now I had to migrate to Fedora 23, because it had better wifi drivers for my notebook.
Anyway,I downloaded Eclipse Mars.2 for c/c++, installed gtk3-devel package, and then pkg-config from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TuononenP/pkg-config.p2/master/site.xml 
but it is not detected by the plugin in eclipse.
I always enter
Project Properties | C/C++ Build | Settings | Pkg-config 
Cairo, glib, pango, etc, everything is listed, except for gtk3 :(
I dont know what else to do, I reinstalled several times the gtk3-devel package with sudo dnf install, no fixing.
I installed eclipse with sudo dnf install eclipse-cdt , same problems.
One curious thing is that if I import to eclipse an old project that I did with gtk+3, it compiles and runs perfectly :/

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem with /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libgdiplus.pc
that causes ... "pkg-config --list-all" to end premiturely (before listing gtk-3.0 etc)

$ pkg-config --list-all |grep gtk
Variable 'libjpeg_prefix' not defined in '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libgdiplus.pc'

As a workaround add
libjpeg_prefix=/usr
to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libgdiplus.pc